# How can I determine whether a controller action has rendered (rather than redirected?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The `performed?` method returns `true` in a controller if the application has redirected or rendered.

How can I determine whether the application rendered (rather than redirected)?

[Judging from the `performed?` docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/performed%3F), I can look at `@performed_render`, but this seems hacky.

### **Edit:** Why do I want to do this?

I'm trying to cache the output of a controller action *only* in the case that it results in a render (and not a redirect). Here's the code I'm using now: (based on [render-caching](http://github.com/ryanb/render-caching))

```
  def render_with_cache(options = {})
    key = ([request.request_uri, request.format] | (options.delete(:key_additions) || [])).join("::")
    body = Rails.cache.read(key)

    if body
      render :text => body
    else
      yield if block_given?
      render unless performed?
      if @performed_render
        Rails.cache.write(key, response.body, options) # :expires_in
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Is this for a functional test?

Comment: And what about `#create` action which didn't redirect back because of validation errors? It renders normally... And many others too

Comment: hey tom, quick question, why not just cache redirects? why specifically do you want to only cache responses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at `@performed_render`. :) You don't explain *why* you need to detect this, so I am unable to suggest alternative solutions.

Answer (score 26):

**Rails 3.2+** now uses a method called [performed?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/performed%3F) for determining whether or not a render or redirect has already been performed.

Contrived example:

```
def index
  redirect_to not_found_path unless authenticated?
  render action: "show_all" unless performed?
end
```

Answer (score 5):

In an after filter, check the codes for the response status .

```
MyController < ActionController
  after_filter :check_response

  # define your actions that render or redirect

  protected

  def check_response
    # put real app logic here
    puts :rendered! if response.status == "200 OK" 
    puts :redirected! if response.status == "302 Found" 

  end
end
```

Comment: `@perfomred_render` is superior. This will fail if you do a 301, for example.

Comment: not so. works fine for me. the response status is "301 Moved Permanently"